# How to download manually the HTML of a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to download manually the HTML of a dynamic page.
I can't use a scraper because the site recognize me.

I tried to inspect the page, but in the Dev Tools I found no way to download the full HTML.
What should I do?
Pardon I'm quite newbie in Computer Science.

Comment: Are you trying to do so automatically? Manually you can just do CTRL+S when you have the page loaded.

Comment: Wow thank you, it was that simple. Anyway I tried to overcome their anti-scrape blockage, but after I tried many solutions I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to download the page just click these buttons on your keyboard

```
CTRL + S
```

That means you will save the current HTML page to your computer.
I hope it's clear and helpful, Thanks!.